# How to create/join chat room using ws (Websocket) package in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ws

I am using **ws** package in server side and I want the client to create/join rooms in server socket. And to remove them from a created room when they are no longer connected.
PS: I don't want to use socketIo.

Comment: I'm on the same requirement. Did you find out the solution?

Comment: No answer so far. I am still searching for the answer

Comment: Are you looking for a websocket client for browsers? Are you looking for a web chat source code? Have you tried something you want to share?

Comment: I am looking for server side  implementation of a webrtc signaling server.

Comment: Here are some tools you can use instead of Socket.io https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API#Tools

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
const rooms = {};

wss.on("connection", socket => {
  const uuid = ...; // create here a uuid for this connection

  const leave = room => {
    // not present: do nothing
    if(! rooms[room][uuid]) return;

    // if the one exiting is the last one, destroy the room
    if(Object.keys(rooms[room]).length === 1) delete rooms[room];
    // otherwise simply leave the room
    else delete rooms[room][uuid];
  };

  socket.on("message", data => {
    const { message, meta, room } = data;

    if(meta === "join") {
      if(! rooms[room]) rooms[room] = {}; // create the room
      if(! rooms[room][uuid]) rooms[room][uuid] = socket; // join the room
    }
    else if(meta === "leave") {
      leave(room);
    }
    else if(! meta) {
      // send the message to all in the room
      Object.entries(rooms[room]).forEach(([, sock]) => sock.send({ message }));
    }
  });

  socket.on("close", () => {
    // for each room, remove the closed socket
    Object.keys(rooms).forEach(room => leave(room));
  });
});
```

This is only a sketch: you need to handle leave room, disconnection from client (leave all rooms) and delete room when nobody is longer in.

Comment: both of your your answer helped me a lot to create my own. Thanks

Comment: You pointed something important in your answer but did not provide a sample. How to know if no body is **no longer in**? and how to remove them from the room. can you please provide a sample? @Daniele Ricci

Comment: Okey. I see that

Comment: const uuid instead of cont uuid in line 3

Comment: Do you use this library https://github.com/websockets/ws? If yes, `const { message, meta, room } = data;` this one is only pseudo code? Or its depends on client library what it's possible to send. Because I use some C# library, and I can send only string. Then probably I should send json and manually transform into similar logic.

Comment: Hi @Aleksandrs; the interface is based on that module yes, but please consider all the example as pseudo code. Last yes, when I have to use layers that allow to send only strings I usually use some functions to encode complex data in strings before sending and the reverse after receive (i.e. in Javascript JSON.stringify/SJON.parse)

Comment: @DanieleRicci hey, may i now in what case the rooms object may be erased when using it with express server, for example when server restarted does it remain  or i need to re-create rooms

Comment: Hi @anie , `const rooms = {};` is in memory and it (obviously) does not persist across restarts. The code I wrote tries to explain the basics behind a WebSockets chat, probably you will need to save data (users, rooms, etc.) on a storage able to persist across Node.js restarts as a DB.

Comment: @DanieleRicci thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 5):

You can create user and room in this way using a socket or without socket

```
const users = [];//It can be collection(noSQL) or table(SQL)

const addUser = ({ id, name, room }) => {
  name = name.trim().toLowerCase();
  room = room.trim().toLowerCase();

  const existingUser = users.find((user) => user.room === room && user.name === name);

  if(!name || !room) return { error: 'Username and room are required.' };
  if(existingUser) return { error: 'Username is taken.' };

  const user = { id, name, room };

  users.push(user);

  return { user };
}
```

Comment: both of your answer helped me a lot to create my own. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000
const WebSocket = require('ws');

function noop() {}

function heartbeat() {
  this.isAlive = true;
}

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port });
var rooms = {};

const paramsExist = (data) =>{
  try {
    if('meta' in data && 'roomID' in data && 'clientID' in data && 'message' in data){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
}

const roomExist = (roomID) =>{
    // check for room is already exist or not
    if(roomID in rooms){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
}

const insideRoomdataExist = (arr,data) =>{
  var status = false;
  for(var i =0; i<arr.length;i++){
    if(data in arr[i]){
      status= true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return status;
}

const clientExistInRoom = (roomID,ws,clientID) =>{
  var status = false;
  const data = rooms[roomID];
  for(var i =0; i< data.length ;i++){
    var temp = data[i];
    // if(roomID in temp){
    //   status=true;
    //   console.log("hello world");
    // }
    for(const obj in temp){
      // if(ws == temp[obj]){
      if(clientID == obj){
        status = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }return status;
}
// create room
const createRoom =(data,ws)=>{
  try {
    var {roomID,clientID} = data;
    const status = roomExist(roomID);
    if(status){
      ws.send(JSON.stringify({
            'message':'room already exist',
            'status':0
          }));
    }else{
      rooms[roomID] = [];
      var obj = {};
      obj[clientID] = ws;
      rooms[roomID].push(obj);
      ws['roomID']=roomID;
      ws['clientID']=clientID;
      ws['admin']=true;
      ws.send(JSON.stringify({
        'message':'room created succesfully',
        'status':1
      }));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
      'message':'there was some problem in creating a room',
      'status':0
    }));
  }
}

// join room 
const joinRoom = (data,ws) => {
  try {
    var {roomID,clientID} = data;
    // check if room exist or not
    const roomExist = roomID in rooms;
    if(!roomExist){
      ws.send(JSON.stringify({
        'message':'Check room id',
        'status':0
      }));
      return;
    }
    // const inRoom = insideRoomdataExist(rooms[roomID],clientID);
    const inRoom = clientExistInRoom(roomID,ws,clientID)
    if(inRoom){
      ws.send(JSON.stringify({
        "message":"you are already in a room",
        "status":0
      }));
    }else{
      var obj = {};
      obj[clientID] = ws;
      rooms[roomID].push(obj);
      ws['roomID']=roomID
      ws['clientID']=clientID;
      ws.send(JSON.stringify({
      "message":"Joined succesfully",
      "status":1
    }));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
      'message':'there was some problem in joining a room',
      'status':0
    }));
  }
}

// send message 
const sendMessage = (data,ws,Status=null) => {
  try {
    var {roomID, message,clientID} = data;
    //check whether room exist or not
    const roomExist = roomID in rooms;
    if(!roomExist){
      ws.send(JSON.stringify({
        'message':'Check room id',
        'status':0
      }));
      return;
    }
    // check whether client is in room or not
    const clientExist = clientExistInRoom(roomID,ws,clientID);
    if(!clientExist){
      ws.send(JSON.stringify({
        'message':"You are not allowed to send message",
        'status':0
      }));
      return;
    }
    const obj = rooms[roomID];
    for(i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
      var temp = obj[i];
      for(var innerObject in temp){
        var wsClientID = temp[innerObject];
        if(ws!==wsClientID){
          wsClientID.send(JSON.stringify({
            'message':message,
            'status':Status?Status:1
          }));
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
      'message':'There was some problem in sending message',
      'status':0
    }));
  }
}

const leaveRoom = (ws,data) => {
  try {
    const {roomID} = data;
    // manual code started------------------------------------------------------------
    const roomExist = roomID in rooms;
    if(!roomExist){
      ws.send(JSON.stringify({
        'message':'Check room id',
        'status':0
      }));
      return;
    }
    if('admin' in ws){
      data['message']="Admin left the room.";
      sendMessage(data,ws,Status=2);
      delete rooms[ws.roomID]
      return;
    }
    else{
      // find the index of object
      lst_obj = rooms[roomID];
      var index = null;
      for(let i=0;i<lst_obj.length;i++){
        var temp_obj = lst_obj[i];
        for(var key in temp_obj){
          var temp_inside = temp_obj[key]
          if('admin' in temp_inside){
            temp_inside.send(JSON.stringify({
              'message':'Somebody leave the room',
              'status':3
            }));
          }
          if(ws==temp_inside){
            index =i;
          }
        }
      }
      if(index!=null){
        rooms[roomID].splice(index,1);
        console.log((rooms[roomID].length));
      }
    }


  } catch (error) {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
      'message':'There was some problem----------------------',
      'status':0
    }))
  }
  
}

const available_room = (ws) =>{
  try {
    var available_room_id=[];
    for(var i in rooms){
      available_room_id.push(parseInt(i));
    }
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
      "rooms":available_room_id,
      "status":4
    }))
  } catch (error) {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
      'message':'There was some problem----------------------',
      'status':0
    }))
  }
}

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  try {
    ws.on('message',(recieveData)=>{
      var data = JSON.parse(recieveData);
      const error = paramsExist(data);
      if(!error){
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({
          'message':'check params',
          'status':0
        }));
        return;
      }
      var {roomID,meta} = data;
      switch (meta) {
        case "create_room":
          createRoom(data,ws);
          console.log(rooms);
          break;
        
        case "join_room":
          joinRoom(data,ws);
          console.log(rooms);
          break;
          
        case "send_message":
          sendMessage(data,ws);
          console.log(rooms);
          break;

        case "show_all_rooms":
          ws.send(JSON.stringify({
            "rooms":[rooms]
          }))
          break;
        default:
          ws.send(JSON.stringify({
            "message":"Unsupported meta data provided provide valid data",
            "status":0
          }));
          break;
      }
    })
    ws.on('close', function(data) {
      leaveRoom(ws,{roomID:ws.roomID,clientID:ws.clientID,message:"Leave request"})
      ws.terminate();
    });

    ws.on('pong', heartbeat);
  } catch (error) {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
      "message":"there was some problem",
      "status":0
    }))
  }
});
const interval = setInterval(function ping() {
  var a = wss.clients;
  wss.clients.forEach(function each(ws) {
    if (ws.isAlive === false) {
      leaveRoom(ws,{roomID:ws.roomID,clientID:ws.clientID});
      ws.terminate();
    }
    ws.isAlive = false;
    ws.ping(noop);
  });
}, 50000);

const serverFree = setInterval(()=>{
  var removeKey = [];
  for(const obj in rooms){
    if(rooms[obj].length<1){
      removeKey.push(obj);
    }
  }
  for(var i =0; i<removeKey.length;i++){
    delete rooms[removeKey[i]];
  }
},30000)
```

Hello there above is the code for socket connection using was. All you need to do is provide JSON from the frontend in the meta key. There are 4 params that you need to send from the frontend in JSON using the socket library.

Required keys
-meta:"create_room"/"join_room"/"send_message"/"show_all_rooms"
-message:"anything"
-roomID:"roomid to create or join"
-clientID:"unique client id"

package.json file dependies

```
{
  "name": "nodesocket",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node src/app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "ws": "^7.4.6"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using Map that stores a channel and an array of WS instead of the array that registers users' rooms.

If you have a lot of users this would be a better approach for sending messages (I implemented these kinds of WS for my company) that can handles easily 40k to 50k (for each node of WS) and send thousands of messages per second.

You can broadcast messages easily (by just getting a room from your Map).

The Map is like this: `Map<String,[]> (room, ws array)`.

And when the user joins a new room just add it into the room's array when he left removes it. (/!\ do not forget to ping users in both directions)

For sending messages to a room just call (avoid calling it without checking if the room exists by using `map.has(channel)`).

```
map.get(room).forEach(ws => ws.send(yourMessage))
```

It also helped me with linear scaling. This array is external from my `wss` and `ws` so while a message is published from REDIS (or anything else), I just put a callback that send the message to the corresponding room. So when you broadcast messages it does not check all the users' rooms.